# Looping Navigation tabs in PHP

Tags: php, html

So the problem is when I try to echo My panes it works fine, but each result get a pane each, what I would like to do is. Let's say each time a call a tab i want 5 results in that tab..
Code:

```
                <?php
                $sql = "select * from progress order by procent asc";
                $query = mysqli_query($db,$sql) or die(mysqli_error($db));
                $nums = mysqli_num_rows($query);

            ?>
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab">
            <?php 
                for($i = 1; $i <= $nums; $i++){
                    if($i == 1){
                        echo "<li class='active'><a href='#active".$i."'>".$i."</a></li>";
                    }else{
                            echo "<li><a href='#active".$i."'>".$i."</a></li>";
                    }
                }
            ?>
        </ul>
        <div id="myTabContent" class="tab-content">

            <?php
                $y = 1;
                $arr = array();
                while($res = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
                if($y == 1){
                    echo '<div class="tab-pane active" id="active'.$y.'">';
                }else{
                    echo '<div class="tab-pane" id="active'.$y.'">';
                }
                        echo $res['workingon'];

                        if($res['procent'] == 100){
                            echo "<i class='icon-color icon-check icon'></i>".$res['procent']."%";
                        }else{
                            echo "<i class='icon-color icon-close icon'></i>".$res['procent']."%";
                        }
                    echo "</div>";
                    $y++;

                }

            ?>

        </div>
```

the ul wraps the tabs..

the div with id=mytabcontents wraps the results
Hope you get this sorry for my bad english :)
regards Cruelcrome

Comment: Don't mix php with html. Please.

Comment: following on from @Lame-up-duck http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/180501/which-is-better-to-include-html-inside-php-code-or-outside-it could be useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
This statement
echo '<div class="tab-pane active" id="active'.$y.'">';
```

may give the id which will be active'somevalue' are you sure about it???

Comment: lets say have 3 panes like so: pane1 pane2 pane3 and the id is what triggers the content of the tab, but as of now i can only get 1 result per pane ? Im very confusing i know :)

Comment: I get all my records but i only get 1 record pr tab

Comment: View source code of your web page is your css with the diffrent class is hiding your data??

Comment: One more where you are establishing the connection